# $_SESSION inside php function executed by AJAX

Tags: plugin-development, ajax, session

I am defining `$_SESSION['session_test']` from `$_POST['reason']` I get from AJAX call.

Inside of this function, `$_SESSION['session_test']` does get defined, and I get desired `echo` result.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_return_reason', array( __CLASS__ , 'select_return_reason'));
static function select_return_reason() {

        $_SESSION['session_test'] = $_POST['reason'];
        echo "REASON: " . $_SESSION['session_test'];
        echo "<br>";

        wp_die();
    }
```

But, when I refresh page and try to echo `$_SESSION['session_test']` in some other function below this one, it's empty - I get NULL.

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_cart_table', array( __CLASS__ , 'display_returned_items'));
static function display_returned_items() {
        echo "Testing: " .  $_SESSION['session_test'];
    }
```

Why `$_SESSION['session_test']` value is available/defined only inside function which is executed by AJAX?

My `session_start();` is on the top of the php file, right after the `<?php` opening tag.

Please let me know if I should provide more info. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrapping this line inside `if` statement solved the problem:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['session_test'])) {
    $_SESSION['session_test'] = $_POST['reason'];
}
```

I thought `select_return_reason(){...}` function which is holding this line was executing only by AJAX, not on each page load.